# Estabilish Relationships in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, modeling

I have 10 tables created in Snowflake. How do i model them? I mean how do i establish relationship between the tables in the form of a parent-child relationship or in the form of Facts and Dimensions?

Can you please share a sample model if you have?

Comment: Snowflake is no different than any other RDBMS in this sense. I suggest you look at database tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake supports defining and maintaining below constraints, however it does not enforce them, except for NOT NULL constraints, which are always enforced.

- UNIQUE
- PRIMARY KEY
- FOREIGN KEY
- NOT NULL

For constraints and related details please refer
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints-overview.html

For sample code/model you can check at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/table-considerations.html